# Setting the value of multiple inputs with the same id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Considering the following HTML:

```
<form id="upvoteForm" method="post" action="/post/upvote">
    <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id"/>
</form>
<form id="downvoteForm" method="post" action="/post/downvote">
    <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id"/>
</form>

<input type="hidden" id="_postid" value="1"/>
```

I'm trying to set the two `input` fields with the name `post_id` to to value from `_postid` using this JavaScript and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#post_id').val($('#_postid').val());
});
```

However, as you can see [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5aa8/), it's only setting the value of the first one. How do I set the value of both of them? I thought the selector would end up grabbing both.

Now, I realize you might be wondering why I have two forms on this page. The basic reason is I have `button` inputs that I've styled the way I want but then I use the `onclick` to call the `submit` of the appropriate form here. I am ultimately going to be leveraging AJAX here, but that's coming later.

Comment: The `id` attribute is always supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

id is always unique. you cannot select 2 elements with same id. select by name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=post_id]').val($('#_postid').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Having two HTML elements with the same ID is illegal and will cause undefined behavior such as what you're experiencing. Using the same name is valid, however. Therefore you could use a selector like `$('form > input[name=post_id]')`, which would look for an `input` inside of a `form` with the `name` attribute set to `post_id`.